# How to have two angucomplete input in the same form?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I change the ng-model of angucomplete.

I substituted:

```
<input class="form-control"
       ng-disabled="checks.school != 1"
       ng-model="items.school"
       placeholder="Type a school..."
       type="text"">
```

With this:

```
<angucomplete-alt
       disable-input="checks.school != 1"
       input-class="form-control form-control-small"
       minlength="1"
       pause="100"
       placeholder="Type a school..."
       remote-url-data-field="results"
       remote-url="{{completeUrl}}/api/users/complete?field=school&phrase="
       selected-object="items.school"
       title-field="result"/>
```

However, I have two inputs of the angucomplete in the same form. Both the ng-model inputs are renderized to searchStr:

```
<input autocapitalize="off"
       autocomplete="off"
       autocorrect="off"
       class="form-control form-control-small"
       disabled="disabled"
       id="items.skills_value"
       maxlength="524288"
       name=""
       ng-blur="hideResults($event)"
       ng-change="inputChangeHandler(searchStr)"
       ng-class="{'angucomplete-input-not-empty': notEmpty}"
       ng-disabled="disableInput"
       ng-focus="onFocusHandler()"
       ng-model="searchStr"
       placeholder="Node.js, Django, Sinatra..."
       type="text">
```

So, how do I bind it to the controller?

Thanks!

Comment: Show us some code, post your code here or create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), [codepen](http://codepen.io) or [jsbin](http://jsbin.com)

Comment: I added the code to the post